# How to delet records with Elastica?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I want to delete records which match date range with `Elastica`

query of `elasticsearch` to delete records

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query' -d '{
"query": {
        "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "gte" : 10,
                "lte" : 20,
                "boost" : 2.0
            }
        }
    }
} '
```

How to this query with Elastica ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
$age_range = new NumericRange('age', array(
    'gte' => 10,
    'lte' => 20,
    'boost' => 2.0
));
$client->getIndex("index-name")->deleteByQuery($age_range);
```

Note that if you are running ES 2.x (any version), you need to install the [delete-by-query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html) first. If you are running ES 1.x or 5.x you don't need to install any additional plugin.

Comment: I cant find deleteByQuery() function in my elastica where this function is ?

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/18b0c890c92744bdd5bd47cc1fc229b9dcd83263/lib/Elastica/Index.php#L151-L156

Comment: I think deleteByQuery() function is defined for index not client, so you have to use it like this:
       $client->getIndex("Your index name")-> deleteByQuery($age_range);

Comment: @MaryamHomayouni you're right, thanks for correcting this. I will update the answer accordingly